# A scipt to (weekly) empty a table in my database

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, shell

I'd like to empty weekly or monthly a table (*SystemEvents*) of my database (*rsyslogdb*) with a scipt shell.

I'm using CentOS 6.4.

Could you help me?

Comment: Create cron for weekly or monthly which truncate your table.

Answer (score 3):

Using MySQL's [event scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/event-scheduler.html):

```sql
CREATE EVENT emptyEventsWeekly ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 WEEK DO
  DELETE FROM rsyslogdb.SystemEvents
```

or

```sql
CREATE EVENT emptyEventsMonthly ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MONTH DO
  DELETE FROM rsyslogdb.SystemEvents
```

Note that you may need to enable the scheduler in order for such events to run, as described under [Event Scheduler Configuration](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/events-configuration.html).